How to stop numpy floats being displayed as "np.float64"?
I have a large library with many doctests. All doctests pass on my computer. When I push changes to GitHub, GitHub Actions runs the same tests in Python 3.8, 3.9, 3.10 and 3.11. All tests run correctly on
on Python 3.8; however, on Python 3.9, 3.10 and 3.11, I get many errors of the following type:
Expected:
    [13.0, 12.0, 7.0]
Got:
    [np.float64(13.0), np.float64(12.0), np.float64(7.0)]

I.e., the results are correct, but for some reason, they are displayed inside "np.float64".
In my code, I do not use np.float64 at all, so I do not know why this happens. Also, as the tests pass on my computer, I do not know how to debug the error, and it is hard to produce a minimal working example.
Is there a way I can make the doctests pass again, without changing each individual test?

What version(s) of NumPy are you using? I would guess that's more relevant than the Python version.

Please provide some example code. For reference see [mre].

@wjandrea my requirements file says numpy>=1.21.3. The code runs on GitHub actions, so I am not sure what version exactly they use.

This is because of a change in numpy 2: https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/2.0.0-notes.html#representation-of-numpy-scalars-changed. You should probably restrict numpy in requirements file to < 2.

@juanpa.arrivillaga there are many other breaking changes in numpy 2. You should either change it to >= 2.0.0 or restrict it to 1.x.x.

Show one or more of the problem doctests

Were you doing something like list(np.array([13.0, 12.0, 7.0]))?

@Dogbert thanks a lot! I changed the line in my requirements.txt file to numpy>=1.21.3,<2.0.0 and the problem is solved!

@Erel You can make up an MRE post-facto thanks to the info Dogbert provided. Say for example, "When I check the logs on GitHub Actions, they're using NumPy 2.[x].[y]" and use the code hpaulj provided. Sidenote: If you are in fact using list(np.ndarray), you should probably use np.ndarray.tolist() instead, which uses Python scalars instead of NumPy scalars.

More that debugging details, this needs a [numpy 2.0] tag.  I'd reopen this, except for the reputation of the closers.

Related: How to print a list of numpy.float32 values? and String representation of numpy objects has changed?

This is due to a change in how scalars are printed in numpy 2:
numpy 1.x.x:
>>> repr(np.array([1.0])[0])
'1.0'

numpy 2.x.x:
>>> repr(np.array([1.0])[0])
'np.float64(1.0)'

You should restrict the version of numpy to be 1.x.x in your requirements file to make sure you don't end up installing numpy 2.x.x:
numpy ~> 1.26

(same as numpy >= 1.26, == 1.*, see this answer)
or update your code to work with numpy 2 and change it to numpy ~> 2.0.

Why is it necessary to specify the version when NumPy 2.0 hasn't been released yet? I'm not super familiar with requirements.txt, but why is pip installing a pre-release version in the first place?

@wjandrea https://pypi.org/project/numpy says 2.0.0 was released on Jun 16.

Oh! The documentation wasn't updated yet when I looked at it earlier today.

numpy allows you to control this without downgrading:
np.set_printoptions(legacy='1.25')

See numpy.set_printoptions for details.
This is also stated here: Representation of NumPy scalars changed - NumPy 2.0.0 Release Notes

This is due to numpy 2 as @Dogbert mentioned. You could specify the print format to get rid of the np.float64:
array = [np.float64(13.0), np.float64(12.0), np.float64(7.0)]
str_array = [f"{x:.2f}" for x in array]
print(f"[{', '.join(str_array)}]")


map(str, array) is better. "{x:.2f}" will unnecessarily remove precision from numbers with > 2 decimal digits.

Note that "{x:f}" be equivalent but yup, using map is much better here.
