How to print a list of numpy.float32 values?
I run some simulations whose result is a dict like this:
results = {
    'this': 5,
    'that': 6,
    'those': [2.34, 5.67]
}

I save it in a human-readable format using code like this:
s = ''
for key, value in results.items():
    s += f'{key}: {value}\n'

One of my values happens to be a list of numpy.float32 values.
All was well until I upgraded to numpy 2.0.0. In this version, the code above produces strings like [np.float32(2.34), np.float32(5.67)] instead of [2.34, 5.67] (which I got in numpy 1.26.1).
Should I complicate my saving code and use different code for saving values of different types? Or is there some workaround which could produce human-readable output for all types, including those composed of float32?

Additional examples (in an interactive python environment):

import numpy
x = numpy.float32(2.3)

x
    numpy 1 — 2.3
    numpy 2 — np.float32(2.3)

f'{x}'
    numpy 1 — '2.299999952316284'
    numpy 2 — '2.299999952316284'

f'{[x, x]}'
    numpy 1 — '[2.3, 2.3]'
    numpy 2 — '[np.float32(2.3), np.float32(2.3)]'

y={x:x*x}
y
    numpy 1 — {2.3: 5.29}
    numpy 2 — {np.float32(2.3): np.float32(5.29)}

I can't make sense of it. Is it a bug that I could expect to be fixed, or a feature which is unlikely to change?

have you read the release notes? There are more than the  usual number of big changes,

Didn't read it all. Looks like a normal big list of miscellaneous changes; too hard to find something specific in it.

I've posted an answer to the question itself, but is it necessary to upgrade to 2.0?

In a recent SO about 2.0, someone posted a link to the relevant paragraph.  Looks like it's intentionally displaying the repr form of these list elements.  There is mention of a legacy display setting.

Is there a [numpy 2.0] tag?  I suspect this is just the start of lots 2.0 specific questions.

Yesterday's 2.0 question, https://stackoverflow.com/q/78630047/901925

As an aside, you should never be relying on the __str__ implementation unless there is some promise in the documentation about the way it will behave. But it isn't clear to me what the actual problem is. How is the new output not human readable? It seems even better now than before

Also, as an aside, a list of np.float32 objects doesn't really make sense to have at all.

For anyone who cares, here's my question that got marked as a duplicate of this one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78634270/string-representation-of-numpy-objects-has-changed

Answered in comments on another question.

This is because of a change in numpy 2 <...> You should probably restrict numpy in requirements file to < 2.

–
Dogbert

https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/2.0.0-notes.html#representation-of-numpy-scalars-changed

Scalars are now printed as np.float64(3.0) rather than just 3.0. This may disrupt workflows that store representations of numbers (e.g., to files) making it harder to read them. <...>


As a workaround, the following will restore numpy 1 behavior:
numpy.set_printoptions(legacy='1.25')


Other than for demo purposes, is there a real need to construct a list of numpy scalars?  I can imaging getting such a list by list(np.array(...)), but np.array(...).tolist() is faster, and shouldn't have this display issue.  list.append is another relatively slow way of getting a list of numpy scalars.

From what I see, f-strings on just a single numpy.float32 will still print just the value as desired, so we just need to address when it's a list of numpy.float32 values.
results = {
    'this': 5,
    'that': np.float32(6),
    'those': [np.float32(2.34), np.float32(5.67)]
}

s = ''
for key, value in results.items():
    if isinstance(value, list):
        s += f'{key}: [' + ', '.join(['{}']*len(value)).format(*value) + ']'
    else:
        s += f'{key}: {value}\n'

print(s)

Output:
this: 5
that: 6.0
those: [2.3399999141693115, 5.670000076293945]


If you enter the array and format each element separately, you can use str instead of f-strings — it's easier and doesn't print extra decimals. I hope for something that is reasonably type-generic (e.g. handles dict, list, tuple, etc).

I could do a switch to hasattr(value, '__iter__') to be more generic and then a ['{:.2}'] to control decimals. Would that work?

@MichaelCao that's probably too general
